# Accessing deeply nested JSON values

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving a JSON from an API and I'm parsing it into a Class like so :

```
class HappyModel {
  HappyModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  final String id;
  final String name;

  factory HappyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> _json) {
    return HappyModel(
        id: _json['_id'].toString(),
        name: _json['name'].toString(),
        );
  }
}
```

*Here is what my JSON looks like (simplified) :*

```
{
    "_id":62348d85433322b995288b41,
    "date":"2022-05-02T00":"00":00.000Z,
    "name":"Happy Name",
    "restaurant":{
       "ticket":615ec9a2ec0a3a001d20abcf,
       "opened":true,
       "offers":{
          "lunch":[
             {
                "_id":4051bae6df66a612ca5d008b,
                "isOnlyForCustomer":false,
                "price":750
             },
             {
                "_id":5051bae6df66a612ca5d003a,
                "isOnlyForCustomer":false,
                "price":1000
             },
             {
                "_id":6051bae6df66a612ca5d007e,
                "isOnlyForCustomer":false,
                "price":1150
             }
          ],
          "evening":[
             {
                "_id":1041bae6df66a612ca5d00ao,
                "isOnlyForCustomer":false,
                "price":1200
             },
             {
                "_id":5051bae6df66a612ca5d000z,
                "isOnlyForCustomer":false,
                "price":750
             },
             {
                "_id":8051bae6df66a612ca5d001a,
                "isOnlyForCustomer":false,
                "price":250
             }
          ]
       },
    "something":null,
    "somethingelse":"aoaoa"
 }
 }
```

I'm trying to access the items (offers) nested inside `"restaurants" -> "offers" -> "lunch"`

something like this :

```
class HappyModel {
  HappyModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.offers,
  });

  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<OfferModel> offers;

  factory HappyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> _json) {
    return HappyModel(
        id: _json['_id'].toString(),
        name: _json['name'].toString(),

// Here ⭐️ I'd like to access the nested json 

        offers: OfferModel.listFromJson(_json['restaurants.offers.lunch']));
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can access this json array nested inside `"restaurants" -> "offers" -> "lunch"` directly, without creating a a restaurant model and so on ?

Since I don't need the other values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to access nested keys of `Map` is to call the `[]` operator several times:

```dart
offers: OfferModel.listFromJson(_json['restaurants']['offers']['lunch'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the nested field via list of index sequence

```
  final value = getNestedValue(
      input,
      indexChain: [
       'automobile',
       'color',
      ],
    );

  print(value);

  // ..

  Map get input => { 
       'automobile' : {
          'color' : 'blue'
        }
   }


  dynamic getNestedValue(
    Map map, {
    required List indexChain,
  }) {
    final index1 = indexChain[0];

    dynamic value = map[index1];

    for (int i = 1; i < indexChain.length; i++) {
      final nextIndex = indexChain[i];

      value = value[nextIndex];
    }

    return value;
  }
```